# Count-voting program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build this in Python. My idea is:

- program starts
- asks how many the candidates are and their names
- continually asks "to who you want to assign your vote?"
- when you're done with voting, simply write "done" and the program print results

## Problem:

- I thought of a list. When the program asks you the number of candidates a list should be created with this number. ex: 5 candidates, create `list [0,1,2,3,4]`, so you can assign Candidate1 to 0, Candidate2 to 1, Candidate3 to 2. But I cannot know how many the candidates will be so I'm trying to figure out how to automate this process in a sort of loops which asks you:

  - how many the candidates are? 5? Perfect, created a `list[0,1,2,3,4]`
  - Insert candidates names:
  - Candidate1: Albert [0]
  - Candidate2: Jonah [1]
  - Candidate3: Misty [2]
  - Candidate4: Donald [3]
  - Candidate5: Mary [4]

Then asks you to assign votes and when you write "done" the program does the maths and gives you result.

Any thoughts? Hope I made my point. Thanks. And sorry for bad english.

**Edit:**

Ok I guess I wasn't clear.

```
candidates = input("How many candidates do we have?\n")
candidates = int(candidates)
print("OK! So we have " + str(candidates) + " votable candidates.")
print("Specify their names!\n")


for candidates_number in range(candidates): 
    print(int(candidates_number)) '''to help me visualize what i'm doing'''


overall = candidates
print(list(range(overall)))
complete_list = range(overall)
print(complete_list) '''to help me visualize what i'm doing'''

for candidate_name in range(complete_list):
    print("Write candidates names.\n")
```

Here I'm stuck because I do not know how to automatize the process of asking the candidate name and connect it to the corresponding number of the list.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what your question is.

Comment: Add the code you tried, many would feel happy to help

Comment: maybe you should take a look at a https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries   Dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right this is what you need:

```
total_candidates = int(input("How many candidates do we have?\n"))
print("OK! So we have {0} votable candidates.".format(total_candidates))
print("Specify their names!")

candidates = []

for candidate_number in range(total_candidates):
    print('Candidate {0}:'.format(candidate_number + 1))
    name = input('Whats the name of this candidate?\n')
    candidate_info = (candidate_number + 1, name)
    candidates.append(candidate_info)

print(candidates)
```

Which will output:

> ```
> How many candidates do we have? 
> 3 OK! So we have 3 votable candidates.
> Specify their names! 
> Candidate 1: Whats the name of this candidate? 
> Albert 
> Candidate 2: Whats the name of this candidate? 
> John 
> Candidate 3: Whats the name of this candidate?
> Peter 
> [(1, 'Albert'), (2, 'John'), (3, 'Peter')]
> ```

The result is a `list` of `tuples`. Just access each of its elements by the index. For example, if you want the name just do `candidate[1]` while iterating through it.

Comment: thank you so much! that's exactly what I was looking for. Now I'll study what you did.